# perimeter and side length linear equation section

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The perimeter of a regular hexagon is 3.04cm less than the perimeter of a regular hexagon. The perimeter of the regular hexagon is 21.06. What is the side length of the regular pentagon?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the second "hexagon" in the first sentence should be "pentagon".  Hint:  What is the perimeter of the pentagon?  As the sides of a regular pentagon are equal, what does that tell you about the length?